# Run bash file (.sh) in nginx

Tags: bash, nginx, sh, rtmp

I want to run a Bash file on my Nginx server. This server receives an RTMP stream, the Bash file converts it to different qualities using `ffmpeg`. The file alone works correctly in the terminal and has executive access.

I wrote this code to configure Nginx but it doesn't work.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        allow publish 127.0.0.1;
        deny publish all;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        exec /my/path/to/transcode.sh $name;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: When you say "has execut(iv)e" access, do you mean chmod u+x?

You may find the answer in your nginx logs. I haven't done RTMP this way for a few years, but I believe you would want to add your nginx process's user id to, say a a "streaming" group, `chown myuser:streaming /my/path/to/transcode.sh`, and `chmod ug+x  /my/path/to/transcode.sh`

Comment: What is the exact meaning of _it doesn't work_??? Things rarely fail silently. You usually get some kind of error message and/or failure code. How about running your script explicitly by bash, i.e. `/usr/bin/bash /my/path/to/transcode.sh $name;`?

Answer (score 1):

The exec directive in your nginx configuration should be enclosed within a 'push' block.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        allow publish 127.0.0.1;
        deny publish all;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            push rtmp://your_destination_url;  # Add your destination URL here
            exec /my/path/to/transcode.sh $name;
        }
    }
}
```